# Get Eclipse to show custom component on graphical xml view

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I have simply extended the ImageView so an image goes full width. Like so:..

```
public class BannerImageView extends ImageView {

    public BannerImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BannerImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BannerImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = width * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

In XML I have declared it as follows:

```
<com.whatever.next.BannerImageView
      android:id="@+id/banner"
      android:src="@+drawable/logo"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I receive the following errors:

> main.xml: Unable to resolve drawable "com.android.layoutlib.bridge.ResourceValue@48537a0f" in attribute "src"

then I get the expected null pointer exceptions.

I am confused as I thought since I am not altering the default behaviour of the ImageView it would show in the graphical layout. I have read through the other similar questions and that confused me some more.

For the record the above code works fine on an actual device.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
android:src="@+drawable/logo"
```

use

```
android:src="@drawable/logo"
```

No `+` for the `src` attribute

Comment: I have another custom component that is far more complex. It essentially draws on the canvas a clock and then animates a second hand that goes round. Do I need to use View.isInEditMode()? Eclipse suggests this but when implementing using this I just get more errors (that annoyingly can't be traced via stack).

Comment: can you put this as separate question and bit more detail? Why you want to override `isInEditMode`?

Comment: I only mention that as Eclipse suggests it. I will post my question separately as you say.